# Update the form state in react-final-form

Tags: react-final-form, final-form

I want to set the form state to invalid based on my custom condition. I need to disable the submit button based on it.

I scanned the react-final-form docs but couldn't find a method for the same. Is there any way of doing it

Answer (score 0):

I would look at any of the "synchronous validation" examples.

[image: Edit React Final Form - Synchronous Record-Level Validation Example]

You *can* disable (gray out) the submit button by doing:

```
<Form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
  {({ handleSubmit, invalid }) => (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      ...fields here...
      <button type="submit" disabled={invalid}>Submit</button>
    </form>
  )}
</Form>
```

But I would recommend against it, as the attempt to submit an invalid form will mark all the fields as `touched`, which is a great way to only show the errors when the user has tried to submit the form.

**If the form has validation errors, submission will be blocked by React Final Form.**

Hope this helps!